Calculating visibility of land from sea when sailing boat
I am trying to calculate visibility of land from sea I.e. from which points in a water body can a ship see the coastline when it travels along the coastline.  The ship has no navigation devices.
If the coastline has cliffs/mountains  I would expect it to be most visible that a coastline which just has a lot of beaches.
I have a digital elevation model of the coast line.
I am going to try calculating this visibility along the coastline by

Create a 10km buffer of the coastline into the sea. This should provided all the possible positions of the ship could sail in
Create a 2km grid with in the buffer, this will provide several different locations within the buffer to measure the visibility from
For every point within the buffer calculate a binary viewshed and extract a colour histogram. If more than 5% of the histogram that it means that the coastline  was visible from that spot

Can anybody see any flaws in this approach ?
The 5% is to remove any noise or points with very little visibility
I am going to use gdal_viewshed to calculate the viewshed

Where do you get the 10km for the buffer from? You could probably see large hills from further away even accounting for the curvature of the earth, all depending on the height of the observer on the ship. Does gdal_viewshed work on spherical earth and let you set observer height? Have you tried your approach to see what it gets?

I am dealing with a ship/boat that is in the iron age, ie no telescopes, marine chronometer, all navigation is done by eyesight.  The design of the ship does not have a way of climbing a mast so your limited to what ever you can see from the deck. I have seen figures of 3 km quote for the limit of sight from one ship to another.  So making the buffer distance 10 km seemed a good choice.

gdal_viewshed seems to potentially consider curvature and atmospheric distortion effect, so for each point in the sea compute any visibility of the DEM from a deck-height offset (2m person's height + 2m deck height?) and mask out the sea area (probably 0 on the DEM). Does that work for you?

I think you need to edit "I have a digital elevation model of the coast line." since the "coast line" sounds like a the actual water:land line. You have a DEM of the coastal area, yes, and maybe a polygon defining the coast so you can crop out visible ocean from visible land areas. Try it and see,

You can check your results using a standard formula from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon
visible_distance_in_km
= 3.57 * ( sqrt(height_of_man_on_ship_in_meters) + sqrt(height_of_terrain_he_is_looking_at_in_meters) )
If you cannot climb your mast and the boat is not a big one, set height_of_man_on_ship_in_meters to 2 meters. For the object he is looking at, it depends of the height of the hills/cliffs/mountains. If you have 2 km high mountains close to the sea the formula gives you:
3,57*(sqrt(2)+sqrt(2000)) = 164.7 km
So it seems your 10 km buffer may not be sufficient.
